# Is it possible to control the uncontrollable input text? - React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input-field

I set the input texts values from state when the user select an item from **SelectField dropdown menu of Material UI library** but when it sets, the input texts become unchangeable and what I need is that when the

Here is the image;
**(Before selecting an item from SelectField dropdown menu)**

[image]

**After selecting an item from dropdown;**

[image]

All the filled input texts now become unchangeable, the empty ones are still changeable as they don't get the value from state.

Here are the codes;

```
<div className="form-group row">
  <label className="col-md-2 control-label">Device ID</label>
  <div className="col-md-10">
    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="deviceId" value={this.state.deviceId} placeholder="Device ID" ref="_deviceId" />
  </div>
</div>
```

My state;

```
state = {
  deviceId: null,
};
```

And I set the input texts, when the user select an item from dropdown;

```
saveDeviceInternal(index, value) {
      if (this.props.templatesList.length > 0){

        let deviceId = value;

        this.setState({deviceId});

      }else{
        let deviceId = this.refs._deviceId.value;

        this.setState({deviceId});

      }
    }
```

Comment: use `defaultValue` instead of `value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this method to your class:

```
handleChange(e) {
    let deviceId = e.currentTarget.id
    this.setState({deviceId: e.target.value});
  }
```

and add it to your input component:

```
<input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} id="deviceId" value={this.state.deviceId} placeholder="Device ID"  ref="_deviceId" />
```